# make a JButton action audible with a "click" sound

Tags: swing, jbutton

Is there a built-in feature to make a Swing JButton audible.  I am interested in a click or beep sound.  I know I can invoke noise making code in the event handler, but I am specifically inquiring about any built-in capability that only needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Swing is only about gui. I think there isn't any built-in feature like that. You should add an action listener to your JButton and handle that feature inside actionPerformed method.

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.addActionListener(listener); //where listener implements ActionListener

//inside your listener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    //play your sound
}
```

For what concern audio playback you can have a look at [java sound api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-140234.html).